# VB.Net Late binding operations cannot be converted to an expression tree

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm getting some VB.Net Late binding operations and getting this error:

> Late binding operations cannot be converted to an expression tree.

I've searched here and can only find solutions to the SQL get data code, not to my problem.

At all my `x.NAME` lines !?

Im new to this so can anyone say me why i get this error..

```
<div>Navn: <%: Html.EditorFor(Function(x) x.Name)%></div>   

<h3>Adresse</h3>   

<div>Linje 1: <%: Html.EditorFor(Function(x) x.Line1)%></div>   
<div>Linje 2: <%: Html.EditorFor(Function(x) x.Line2)%></div>   
<div>Linje 3: <%: Html.EditorFor(Function(x) x.Line3)%></div>   
<div>Postnr: <%: Html.EditorFor(Function(x) x.Zip)%></div>   
<div>By: <%: Html.EditorFor(Function(x) x.City)%></div>   
<div>Landsdel: <%: Html.EditorFor(Function(x) x.Country)%></div>   

<h3>Tilvalg</h3>   
<label>   
    <%: Html.EditorFor(Function(x) x.GiftWrap)%>   
    Disse vare skal i Gaveindpakning.   
</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use strongly typed helpers like `Html.EditorFor` while your view is not strongly typed to a class. So you need to indicate the model type in the `@Page` definition:

```
<%@ Page 
    Language="VB" 
    MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage(Of YourApplication.YourModelClass)" %>
```

Notice how the view is now strongly typed to the model class `YourApplication.YourModelClass`. Now you can safely use those helper methods:

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(Function(x) x.Name)%>
```

Comment: I use this in the top                                              <%@ Page Language="vb" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Store.WebUI.Entities.ShippingDetails>" %>  do i need to changes that !?

Comment: @user514993, that's C# syntax. You need to change it as in my example if you want VB.NET.

Comment: ok he he im new to this and its a C# code thats have been converted so dident know that < have to be ( but i do that now. THX