# Type 'Store.WebUI.Entities.ShippingDetails' is not defined & 'BeginForm' is not a member of 'Html'

Tags: vb.net

I had some vb-net-late-binding-operations-cannot-be-converted-to-an-expression-tree errors 
[VB.Net Late binding operations cannot be converted to an expression tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237181/vb-net-late-binding-operations-cannot-be-converted-to-an-expression-tree)

I changes the page code from

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Store.WebUI.Entities.ShippingDetails>" %>
```

to

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage(Of Store.WebUI.Entities.ShippingDetails)" %>
```

that fix the error about late-binding-operations-cannot-be-converted-to-an-expression-tree 
But now i get this error.
- Type 'Store.WebUI.Entities.ShippingDetails' is not defined.   12  5
- 'Context' is not a member of 'ASP.views_cart_checkout_aspx'.  12  5
- 'BeginForm' is not a member of 'Html'.    12  15

My code is

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage(Of Store.WebUI.Entities.ShippingDetails)" %>
```

NetButik : Færdiggør Ordre

```
<h2>Betaling</h2>
Venligst indtast dine personlige data og vi vil sende deres vare hurtigst muligt!

<% Using (Html.BeginForm())%>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary() %>

    <h3>Sendes til</h3>

    <div>Navn: <%: Html.EditorFor(Function(x) x.Name)%></div>

    <h3>Adresse</h3>
    <div>Linje 1: <%: Html.EditorFor(Function(x) x.Line1)%></div>
    <div>Linje 2: <%: Html.EditorFor(Function(x) x.Line2)%></div>
    <div>Linje 3: <%: Html.EditorFor(Function(x) x.Line3)%></div>
    <div>Postnr: <%: Html.EditorFor(Function(x) x.Zip)%></div>
    <div>By: <%: Html.EditorFor(Function(x) x.City)%></div>
    <div>Landsdel: <%: Html.EditorFor(Function(x) x.Country)%></div>

    <h3>Tilvalg</h3>
    <label>
        <%: Html.EditorFor(Function(x) x.GiftWrap)%>
        Disse vare skal i Gaveindpakning.
    </label>

    <p align="center"><input type="submit" value="Færdiggør ordre" /></p>
<% End Using%>
```

Comment: no one that can help. !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that class Store.WebUI.Entities.ShippingDetails exists, reference to System.Web.Mvc.dll exists in your solution. If this doesn't help, post class `Store.WebUI.Entities.ShippingDetails` here, please.